# Access input data from dynamically created FormTextFields with validation in Flutter

Tags: flutter, textfield, formbuilder

I created a custom `FormBuilderTextField` with built in validation and am able to build them when called through `LisView.Builder`. My problem now is that I am unable to access the data within each generated `FormBuilderTextField` and pass that data to another page. I have a `GlobalKey<FormState>()` on the page with the `ListView.Builder` but cant seem to access that data. Any advice?

***Custom TextField***

```
  TextFieldEntry({
    required this.name,
  });

  final String name;

  final myDecorationField = InputDecoration(
    labelText: 'textFieldName',
    labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.pink),
    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topRight: Radius.circular(0),
        bottomRight: Radius.circular(0),
      ),
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        width: 1,
        color: Colors.pink,
      ),
    ),
    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topRight: Radius.circular(0),
        bottomRight: Radius.circular(0),
      ),
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: Colors.pink,
        width: 1,
      ),
    ),
  );

  @override
  State<TextFieldEntry> createState() => _TextFieldEntryState();
}

class _TextFieldEntryState extends State<TextFieldEntry> {
  Input model = Input();
  var _validator;
  var _keyboard;
  var _myUnit;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var _onSaved = (value) {
      model.title = value;
    };
    if (widget.name == 'height') {
      final heightValidate = FormBuilderValidators.compose([
        FormBuilderValidators.required(context),
        FormBuilderValidators.numeric(context),
        FormBuilderValidators.max(context, 200),
        FormBuilderValidators.min(context, 30)
      ]);

      _validator = heightValidate;

      _keyboard = TextInputType.number;
      _myUnit = MyUnit();
    } else {
      final weightValidate = FormBuilderValidators.compose([
        FormBuilderValidators.required(context),
        FormBuilderValidators.numeric(context),
        FormBuilderValidators.max(context, 450),
        FormBuilderValidators.min(context, 30)
      ]);

      _validator = weightValidate;
      _keyboard = TextInputType.number;
      _myUnit = MyUnit(imperial: 'lbs', metric: 'kg');
    } 
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 375, maxHeight: 50),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: FormBuilderTextField(
                    name: widget.name,
                    decoration: widget.myDecorationField
                        .copyWith(labelText: widget.name),
                    onSaved: _onSaved,
                    validator: _validator,
                    keyboardType: _keyboard,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.pink, width: 2)),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                        child: Center(
                          child: ValueListenableBuilder<Units>(
                              valueListenable: _myUnit,
                              builder: (context, unit, _) => AutoSizeText(
                                    _myUnit.unitType,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontSize: 20,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                  )),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Builder(
                        builder: (context) {
                          if (widget.name == 'height' ||
                              widget.name == 'weight' ||
                              {
                            return Container(
                              constraints:
                                  BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 50, maxWidth: 60),
                              child: TextButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Units unit = _myUnit.unit;
                                  _myUnit.unit = unit == Units.unit1
                                      ? Units.unit2
                                      : Units.unit1;
                                },
                                child: Center(
                                  child: Icon(
                                    Icons.loop,
                                    size: 30,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          } else {
                            return Text('');
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 12,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

***ListView.Builder Page***

```
  var title;

  Input({this.title});
}

class BMI extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'BMI';

  @override
  State<BMI> createState() => _BMIState();
}

class _BMIState extends State<BMI> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  List<Input> _bmiInputs = [
    Input(title: 'height'),
    Input(title: 'weight'),
    Input(title: 'gender'),
  ];


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: CustomAppBar(
          title: 'BMI',
        ),
        drawer: MainDrawer(),
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(children: [
          Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 500, maxWidth: 375),
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: _bmiInputs.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext inp, index) {
                      return FittedBox(
                        child: TextFieldEntry(
                                name: _bmiInputs[index].title,
                              ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                    child: Text('Calculate'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _formKey.currentState?.save();
                      if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {}

                      print('Calculate');


// need to access Data here to pass to the calculator


                      // BMICalc bmiCalc;
                      // bmiCalc = BMICalc(
                      //     height: ______,
                      //     weight: ______,
                      //     gender: _______,
                      //     );

                      Navigator.push(context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ResultsScreen(bmi: bmiCalc.calculateBMI(),)));
                    })
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ])));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you use the onSaved as a parameter, you can get Data back to the first Widget
in the FormBuilderTextField it will be at the **onSaved**

ListView.Builder

```
return FittedBox(
          child: TextFieldEntry(
                    name: _bmiInputs[index].title,
                    onSaved: (value) {
                        _bmiInputs[index].title = value;
                    }),
                );
```

TextFieldEntry

```
typedef OnSaved(value);

TextFieldEntry({
  required this.name, required this.onSaved
});

final String name;
final OnSaved onSaved;

...
...

FormBuilderTextField(
                name: widget.name,
                decoration: widget.myDecorationField
                    .copyWith(labelText: widget.name),
                onSaved: widget.onSaved,
                validator: _validator,
                keyboardType: _keyboard,
              ),
```